# Shouldn't there (is there?) be an easier way to convert and sum a pandas column series into integers etc?

Tags: python, pandas, integer, series

After trying various options with `apply, lambda, isnull, etc.`, here is simplest way I could find:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [ 'a', '100' ],
    [ 'b', '' ],
    [ 'c', '300' ],
])
print(df)
pd.to_numeric(df[1]).dropna().astype(int).sum()
```

It works but seems convoluted.  Also annoying to have to use `dropna` as I previously tried `astype(int, errors='ignore')` but that produces a float because it replaces blanks with `NaN`.

The `to_numeric/dropna/astype/sum` is the simplest way I could find to convert and sum up a column with strings and numbers.  I would have like to used a more robust `to_numeric` or even an `as_numeric` or something else but they are not available for series types.

Anyone got a simpler cleaner way?

Comment: There are tons of ways to do that. Such as `int(pd.to_numeric(df[1]).sum())`. But the problem is, if the second column is supposed to be integer column, should you change the data type at the beginning? It will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop one step with a slight reorder but there's nothing overly simple.

```
pd.to_numeric(df[1]).sum().astype(int)
```